# Why can´t I access a json array of objects like this?

Tags: json, angularjs

This from a test i made because my original json file changed, now i have to change the code, but i not quite familiar with json, this is the file json file http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=96cf940bda26a2e9ddff786f3aacf1d8

```
<!-- this works --> 
                            <table>
                            <tr  ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu[0]">
                            <td ng-repeat="opc in menuOpcion.indicadores">
                            {{opc.tipo}}
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>


                            <br><br><br>
                        <!--nothing below works --> 

                            <table>
                            <tr >
                            <td ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu[0].indicadores">
                            {{menuOpcion.tipo}}
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table>
                            <tr >
                            <td ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu[0]">
                            {{menuOpcion.indicadores.tipo}}
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
```

this is causing me trouble because i have more nested objects in other json files that i need to iterate too, so there is a way to get directly to *indicadores* levels?

i tried this too:

```
                            <table>
                            <tr >
                            <td ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu[0].indicadores[0]">
                            {{menuOpcion.tipo}}
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON structure:

```
array menu [
    0 => 
        object {
            object opciones{
                array indicadores [
                    n => 
                        object indicadore {
                            string tipo
                        }
                ]
            }
        }
)
```

So, try:

```
<table ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu[0]">
    <tr ng-repeat="indicadore in menuOpcion.opciones.indicadores">
        <td>
            {{indicadore.tipo}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu[0]">
        <td ng-repeat="indicadore in menuOpcion.opciones.indicadores">
            {{indicadore.tipo}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

.. based on what you want to achieve.

Comment: hmm not working, i printed the menu[0] to see the contents, it's actually the level in opciones

Comment: You meant, it shows object with `opciones` property or with `nombre` and `indicadores` properties?

Comment: which one: `opciones` **or** `nombre`, `indicadores` without `opciones` prorerty by itself?